# How to correct sampling effort bias?

Tags: r, sampling, biostatistics, bias

I am working on a dataset based on different sites, where each site has several transects. However, the sampling effort is not the same for each site (8th or 6th order sampling strength), which poses a problem for my further statistical analysis. By doing some research, it seems that adopting a sampling approach across the dataset makes the most sense to correct my data.

The idea would be to randomly collect 6 transects per site, to have the same sampling effort. And to repeat this sampling a large number of times using a for loop.

I can't figure out how to design this loop properly, any ideas?

Here is a brief overview of my data with sites from 1.1 to 13.2 :

[image]

Comment: How are you defining "sampling strength"? Does 8th order mean that 1 in every 8 eligible units is sampled?

Comment: Analyzing transect sampling usually benefits from some kind of model of *detectability* of the subjects along the transect (and as a function of distance from it).  Steven Thompson discusses this in detail in his book [*Sampling.*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118162934)

Comment: @AdamO Each transect represents an observation of the species present on a site from a defined point. Each of the 6 or 8 observations per site were made at the same distance from this starting point, but in a random direction. What I mean by sample strenght is the number of observations made per site, i.e. 6 or 8.